# Categorize, label or organize GitHub pull requests?

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to organize pull requests on GitHub? For a big project with lots of contributors and pull requests, it seems like it would be invaluable for admins to at least be able to label pull requests. I would think this would be possible somewhere on the site but I'm not seeing it. I do see Issue labels though.

Comment: There’s an issue associated with each pull request; organizing these issues doesn’t solve the problem for you?

Comment: Actually I think it might. It's just that there are a ton of non-pull request issues as well so they'll have to be organized some way also. Thanks.

Comment: Problem is you cannot label pull request issues. You can only label "normal" issues. Or if you find a way let me know.

Comment: @MikaTuupola it seems like it would be very important to be able to lable them. Being able to label a pull request as "Bug Fix" or "Feature Addition" or "Documentation Change" etc... Can't imagine why this isn't in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note (April 2014): in the blog post "[L is for Labels](https://github.com/blog/1815-l-is-for-labels)", GitHub announce the possibility to easily edit a label on existing issue with the <kbd>l</kbd> hotkey:

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/47/2582431/1855dc10-b9c5-11e3-8cf1-9aa2943d7499.gif]

That would apply to pull request as well, in its conversation tab.

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't notice this change.

Answer (score 21):

There actually is a way to label pull requests but you have to do it from the issues view. Here's the steps:

1. Go to the issues screen
2. Check the box next to the pull request you want to label.
3. At the top of the issues list there is a "Label" button with a little down arrow on it. Click that button.
4. Select the label(s) you want to add to the pull request and then select update.

Not sure why they don't provide a way to label the pull requests the same as issues but this workaround gets the job done.

**Update: 2/7/2014**

GitHub now supports managing labels directly on pull requests.  See their [blog post](https://github.com/blog/1767-redesigned-conversations) for more information.

Comment: Note that you may not be able to add labels to issues/pull requests if you don't manage or own the repository, or if you don't have privileges to manage labels there. For example if you fork a project, you can add labels to issues in your fork, but you may not be able to add labels in issues in the upstream repository.

Answer (score 2):

Shameless self-promotion here, but I've uploaded a Greasemonkey script that adds support for label management directly on pull requests, just like with issues: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/185095

It continues to mystify me that GitHub doesn't support this anyways.  It was very easy to add to the page and didn't contribute a great deal more clutter.