# How the docker git repo is showing different tags in pull requests like status/need-review

Tags: github, tags, docker, pull-request

How the docker git repo is showing different tags in pull requests like status/need-review? What are the plugins they are using. Is the same one can be used for bitbucket, if not is there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because [GitHub proposes to add labels to pull requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22807352/6309) (See [GitHub help](https://help.github.com/articles/applying-labels-to-issues-and-pull-requests/) for pull requests)

BitBucket, in its "[Work with pull requests](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Work+with+pull+requests)", does not mention (yet, May 2015) a similar feature.

The [OP rohit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3929266/rohit) asks [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30388521/how-the-docker-git-repo-is-showing-different-tags-in-pull-requests-like-status-n/30390449#comment48883354_30390449):

> do you have any idea how it actually happening automatically?
>   Like as soon as I send a pull request to docker it shows `status0/need-triage` etc... labels. In the complete process tags for different stages like `status2/need-code-review` etc are assigned.
>   Is the docker administrators are assigning them manually?

That must be a [webhook](https://help.github.com/articles/about-webhooks) ([Webhooks API](https://developer.github.com/webhooks)) set on the docker GitHub repo, which will detect the new PR and automatically label it.

[Vincent Demeester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89249/vincent-demeester) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30388521/how-the-docker-git-repo-is-showing-different-tags-in-pull-requests-like-status-n/30390449#comment48904560_30390449):

> look for a project called [`gh-patch-parser`](https://github.com/jfrazelle/gh-patch-parser), it's [Jessie Frazelle](https://github.com/jfrazelle) who's maintaining this ;-)
>   And yeah it's using webhooks and the GitHub api.

Comment: @@ VonC do you have any idea how it actually happening automatically. Like as soon as I send a pull request to docker it shows status0/need-triage etc.. labels. In the complete process tags for different stages like status2/need-code-revie etc are assigned. Is the docker administrators are assigning them manually?

Comment: @rohit that must be a webhook (https://help.github.com/articles/about-webhooks/, https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) set on the docker GitHub repo, which will detect the new PR and automatically label it.

Comment: @rohit look for a project called gh-patch-parser (https://github.com/jfrazelle/gh-patch-parser), it's jessie frazelle who's maintaining this ;-) and yeah it's using webhooks and the github api

Comment: @VincentDemeester thats a really interesting project. Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: @VincentDemeester Thank you for this comment. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.